# Randoop junit generator pupulates null value for parameter values

Tags: java, junit, randoop

I'm using Randoop to generate Junit and it is always  passing null values when the parameter is not a premitive type for example i have class ClassA which has methods with non-premitive type as parameter for example when the mehtod methodString(String str, Entity entity) is tested the Junits generated has null values for Entity value passed and it does not create a valid object that can be passed.

Edit: I'm using eclipse to run the tests so i have added the necessary jars needed for running Randoop in classpath and below are the args i passed

**gentests --testclass=test.ClassA --time-limit=60**

Note: i'm not able to add images yet. so i'm not able to share the eclipse run command window.

How to configure Randoop to pass non null values for Junit testing.

ClassA

```
  package test;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class ClassA {

    public void method(String str, Calendar date) {

        String  a ="a";
        String  b ="b";
        String  c ="c";
        String  d ="d";

        if(a.equals(str)) {
            System.out.println("True");
        }else if(a.equals(str)) {
            System.out.println("True");
        }else if(c.equals(str)) {
            System.out.println("True");
        }else if(b.equals(str)) {
            System.out.println("True");
        }else if(d.equals(str)) {
            System.out.println("True");
        }
    }

public void method2(String str, Entity entity) {

        String  a ="a";
        String  b ="b";
        String  c ="c";
        String  d ="d";

        if(a.equals(str)) {
            System.out.println("True");
        }else if(a.equals(str)) {
            System.out.println("True");
        }else if(c.equals(str)) {
            System.out.println("True");
        }else if(b.equals(str)) {
            System.out.println("True");
        }else if(d.equals(str)) {
            System.out.println("True");
        }

        if(entity.getName().equals("Sting")) {
            System.out.println("name");
        } else if (entity.getEmail().equals("Sting")){
            System.out.println("email");
        }       
    }
}
```

Entity Class

```
package test;

public class Entity {

    private String name;
    private String email;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    } 

}
```

Sample Junit Generated

```
import org.junit.FixMethodOrder;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runners.MethodSorters;

@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class RegressionTest3 {

    public static boolean debug = false;

    @Test
    public void test001() throws Throwable {
        if (debug)
            System.out.format("%n%s%n", "RegressionTest3.test001");
        test.ClassA classA0 = new test.ClassA();
        java.util.Calendar calendar2 = null;
        classA0.method("hi!", calendar2);
        java.util.Calendar calendar5 = null;
        classA0.method("hi!", calendar5);
        java.util.Calendar calendar8 = null;
        classA0.method("", calendar8);
        java.lang.Class<?> wildcardClass10 = classA0.getClass();
        java.util.Calendar calendar12 = null;
        classA0.method("hi!", calendar12);
        java.lang.Class<?> wildcardClass14 = classA0.getClass();
        java.util.Calendar calendar16 = null;
        classA0.method("hi!", calendar16);
        java.util.Calendar calendar19 = null;
        classA0.method("hi!", calendar19);
        test.Entity entity22 = null;
        try {
            java.lang.String str23 = classA0.methodString("hi!", entity22);
            org.junit.Assert.fail("Expected exception of type java.lang.NullPointerException; message: null");
        } catch (java.lang.NullPointerException e) {
        }
        org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull(wildcardClass10);
        org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull(wildcardClass14);
    }

    @Test
    public void test002() throws Throwable {
        if (debug)
            System.out.format("%n%s%n", "RegressionTest3.test002");
        test.ClassA classA0 = new test.ClassA();
        java.util.Calendar calendar2 = null;
        classA0.method("hi!", calendar2);
        java.util.Calendar calendar5 = null;
        classA0.method("hi!", calendar5);
        java.lang.Class<?> wildcardClass7 = classA0.getClass();
        java.lang.Class<?> wildcardClass8 = classA0.getClass();
        java.util.Calendar calendar10 = null;
        classA0.method("hi!", calendar10);
        java.util.Calendar calendar13 = null;
        classA0.method("", calendar13);
        java.util.Calendar calendar16 = null;
        classA0.method("hi!", calendar16);
        java.util.Calendar calendar19 = null;
        classA0.method("", calendar19);
        java.util.Calendar calendar22 = null;
        classA0.method("", calendar22);
        java.util.Calendar calendar25 = null;
        classA0.method("", calendar25);
        org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull(wildcardClass7);
        org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull(wildcardClass8);
    }

    @Test
    public void test003() throws Throwable {
        if (debug)
            System.out.format("%n%s%n", "RegressionTest3.test003");
        test.ClassA classA0 = new test.ClassA();
        java.util.Calendar calendar2 = null;
        classA0.method("", calendar2);
        java.util.Calendar calendar5 = null;
        classA0.method("", calendar5);
        java.lang.Class<?> wildcardClass7 = classA0.getClass();
        java.util.Calendar calendar9 = null;
        classA0.method("", calendar9);
        java.lang.Class<?> wildcardClass11 = classA0.getClass();
        java.lang.Class<?> wildcardClass12 = classA0.getClass();
        java.lang.Class<?> wildcardClass13 = classA0.getClass();
        java.util.Calendar calendar15 = null;
        classA0.method("hi!", calendar15);
        java.util.Calendar calendar18 = null;
        classA0.method("", calendar18);
        test.Entity entity21 = null;
        try {
            classA0.method2("", entity21);
            org.junit.Assert.fail("Expected exception of type java.lang.NullPointerException; message: null");
        } catch (java.lang.NullPointerException e) {
        }
        org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull(wildcardClass7);
        org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull(wildcardClass11);
        org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull(wildcardClass12);
        org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull(wildcardClass13);
    }
```

Comment: What is the exact command line that you passed Randoop?  Without knowing that, others cannot reproduce your problem or guess what might be happening.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Randoop is not able to generate test cases for abstract classes, in this case java.util.Calendar.

You can supply, on the command line or in a classlist file, the names of the classes that extend the abstract class. For example u can execute Randoop with --classlist=myclasses instead of --testclass=test.ClassA; and in myclasses file (without any extension in the name), put:

```
test.ClassA
java.util.GregorianCalendar
```

I do that and Randoop generate some tests like:

```
import org.junit.FixMethodOrder;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runners.MethodSorters;

@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class RegressionTest1 {

  public static boolean debug = false;

  @Test
  public void test001() throws Throwable {

    if (debug) { System.out.format("%n%s%n","RegressionTest1.test001"); }


    test.ClassA classA0 = new test.ClassA();
    java.util.GregorianCalendar gregorianCalendar2 = new java.util.GregorianCalendar();
    java.lang.String str3 = gregorianCalendar2.getCalendarType();
    classA0.method("java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=?,areFieldsSet=false,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id=\"America/Argentina/Cordoba\",offset=-10800000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=62,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=2,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2018,MONTH=5,WEEK_OF_YEAR=23,WEEK_OF_MONTH=2,DAY_OF_MONTH=7,DAY_OF_YEAR=158,DAY_OF_WEEK=5,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=1,AM_PM=1,HOUR=7,HOUR_OF_DAY=5,MINUTE=18,SECOND=8,MILLISECOND=53,ZONE_OFFSET=-10800000,DST_OFFSET=0]", (java.util.Calendar)gregorianCalendar2);
    java.util.GregorianCalendar gregorianCalendar6 = new java.util.GregorianCalendar();
    int i7 = gregorianCalendar6.getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek();
    java.util.Date date8 = gregorianCalendar6.getGregorianChange();
    int i10 = gregorianCalendar6.getMaximum(3);
    java.util.GregorianCalendar gregorianCalendar11 = new java.util.GregorianCalendar();
    int i12 = gregorianCalendar11.getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek();
    java.util.Date date13 = gregorianCalendar11.getGregorianChange();
    boolean b15 = gregorianCalendar11.isSet(16);
    int i17 = gregorianCalendar11.getActualMaximum(9);
    gregorianCalendar11.setLenient(false);
    int i20 = gregorianCalendar6.compareTo((java.util.Calendar)gregorianCalendar11);
    int i21 = gregorianCalendar6.getWeeksInWeekYear();
    int i23 = gregorianCalendar6.getGreatestMinimum(10);
    classA0.method("", (java.util.Calendar)gregorianCalendar6);
    java.util.Calendar calendar26 = null;
    classA0.method("java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1528409887986,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id=\"America/Argentina/Cordoba\",offset=-10800000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=62,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=2,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2018,MONTH=5,WEEK_OF_YEAR=23,WEEK_OF_MONTH=2,DAY_OF_MONTH=7,DAY_OF_YEAR=158,DAY_OF_WEEK=5,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=1,AM_PM=1,HOUR=7,HOUR_OF_DAY=19,MINUTE=18,SECOND=7,MILLISECOND=986,ZONE_OFFSET=-10800000,DST_OFFSET=0]", calendar26);
    java.util.GregorianCalendar gregorianCalendar29 = new java.util.GregorianCalendar();
    int i30 = gregorianCalendar29.getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek();
    java.util.Date date31 = gregorianCalendar29.getGregorianChange();
    int i33 = gregorianCalendar29.getMaximum(3);
    gregorianCalendar29.setLenient(false);
    boolean b36 = gregorianCalendar29.isWeekDateSupported();
    classA0.method("java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1528409888438,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id=\"America/Argentina/Cordoba\",offset=-10800000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=62,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=2,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2018,MONTH=5,WEEK_OF_YEAR=23,WEEK_OF_MONTH=2,DAY_OF_MONTH=7,DAY_OF_YEAR=158,DAY_OF_WEEK=5,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=1,AM_PM=1,HOUR=7,HOUR_OF_DAY=19,MINUTE=18,SECOND=8,MILLISECOND=438,ZONE_OFFSET=-10800000,DST_OFFSET=0]", (java.util.Calendar)gregorianCalendar29);
    java.util.GregorianCalendar gregorianCalendar39 = new java.util.GregorianCalendar();
    int i40 = gregorianCalendar39.getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek();
    java.util.Date date41 = gregorianCalendar39.getGregorianChange();
    int i43 = gregorianCalendar39.getMaximum(3);
    gregorianCalendar39.setLenient(false);
    boolean b46 = gregorianCalendar39.isWeekDateSupported();
    java.util.GregorianCalendar gregorianCalendar47 = new java.util.GregorianCalendar();
    gregorianCalendar47.setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(0);
    int i51 = gregorianCalendar47.get(10);
    int i52 = gregorianCalendar47.getWeeksInWeekYear();
    boolean b53 = gregorianCalendar39.after((java.lang.Object)gregorianCalendar47);
    gregorianCalendar47.set(1, 30, 10, 3, 5);
    java.util.GregorianCalendar gregorianCalendar60 = new java.util.GregorianCalendar();
    int i61 = gregorianCalendar60.getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek();
    java.util.Date date62 = gregorianCalendar60.getGregorianChange();
    gregorianCalendar60.roll(4, false);
    java.lang.Object obj66 = null;
    boolean b67 = gregorianCalendar60.before(obj66);
    gregorianCalendar60.setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(11);
    boolean b70 = gregorianCalendar47.before((java.lang.Object)gregorianCalendar60);
    classA0.method("java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=?,areFieldsSet=false,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id=\"America/Argentina/Cordoba\",offset=-10800000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=62,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=2,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2018,MONTH=5,WEEK_OF_YEAR=23,WEEK_OF_MONTH=2,DAY_OF_MONTH=7,DAY_OF_YEAR=158,DAY_OF_WEEK=5,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=1,AM_PM=1,HOUR=7,HOUR_OF_DAY=5,MINUTE=18,SECOND=8,MILLISECOND=658,ZONE_OFFSET=-10800000,DST_OFFSET=0]", (java.util.Calendar)gregorianCalendar47);
    test.Entity entity73 = null;
    // The following exception was thrown during execution in test generation
    try {
      classA0.method2("java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=?,areFieldsSet=false,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id=\"America/Argentina/Cordoba\",offset=-10800000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=62,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=2,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2018,MONTH=5,WEEK_OF_YEAR=23,WEEK_OF_MONTH=2,DAY_OF_MONTH=7,DAY_OF_YEAR=158,DAY_OF_WEEK=5,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=1,AM_PM=1,HOUR=7,HOUR_OF_DAY=5,MINUTE=18,SECOND=7,MILLISECOND=993,ZONE_OFFSET=-10800000,DST_OFFSET=0]", entity73);
      org.junit.Assert.fail("Expected exception of type java.lang.NullPointerException");
    } catch (java.lang.NullPointerException e) {
      // Expected exception.
      if (! e.getClass().getCanonicalName().equals("java.lang.NullPointerException")) {
        org.junit.Assert.fail("Expected exception of type java.lang.NullPointerException, got " + e.getClass().getCanonicalName());
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Adrian, let me check this solution